# `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT FROM` in Oracle Cloud doesn't create a new table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle18c

I was trying to create a series of tables in a single SQL query in Oracle Cloud under the ADMIN account. In the minimum script below, `RAW_TABLE` refers to an existing table.

```
CREATE TABLE BASE1 AS SELECT * FROM RAW_TABLE;
CREATE TABLE BASE2 AS SELECT * FROM BASE1;
CREATE TABLE BASE3 AS SELECT * FROM BASE2;
SELECT * FROM BASE3
```

This returns a view of the first 100 rows in `BASE3`, but it doesn't create the three tables along the way. Did I miss something or is there something peculiar about `create table` statements in Oracle SQL?

EDIT: **The environment is Oracle Database Actions in Oracle Cloud**. The three tables would not be available in the list of tables in the database, and doing something like `select * from BASE3` in a subsequent query would fail.

Comment: This doesn't create any views and if `base3` is created, so are the other tables.

Comment: @GordonLinoff What do I need to do explicitly to add these tables into the database?

Comment: If there were no errors, then the tables were created. There is nothing else for you to do.

Comment: Why do you say that the tables are not created. If you are trying to access the tables from some other application, then it could be a permission issue.

Comment: If base3 returned x rows that implies tables base2 and base1 created since base3 is created from base2 and base2 is created from base1.

Comment: Maybe you'll have more *luck* with `SELECT count(*) FROM BASE3` and similar query for `base2` and `1`.  `select *` may return only the first `fetch size` rows, so not all of them.

Comment: @pmdba @Sarun @Suresh what I meant was that the tables were simply not in the database after the query was run. Doing a ``select * from BASE3`` immediately after would throw an error “ORA-00942: table or view does not exist”. Note that this is inside Oracle Database Actions in Oracle Cloud.

Comment: That comment is vastly different to what you state in the question which is that "SELECT * FROM BASE3 This returns a view of the first 100 rows in BASE3..." so which is it? 1. the query returns rows, or 2. the query returns an error that the base3 table does not exist? It cannot be both.

Comment: This looks like a Transaction issue, you can see the BASE3 table immediately because it is in the same transaction. If you add another line selecting from BASE1 and execute it all, it will probably work. Once you close the transaction without committing (or your are out of the transaction, depending of the scope level), all your work is reverted (or is not visible to the outside of the transaction, again depending on the transaction scope level).

Comment: @Bruno - DDL commits (twice; before and after the actual work), so something would have to be dropping the tables later.

Comment: @BrunoCanettieri - because [that's what Oracle does](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:7072180788422), unless you run the DDL in an autonomous transaction or create a private temporary table; but even then the create itself is still committed; only other DML won't be.

Comment: @Alex Poole - But you could have the AUTOCOMMIT off no? sorry, don't really have an oracle db ready to test it - Fore references purposes (removed to make it better, but he responded first) my original comment was: why do you say that? is it a particularity of "Oracle Database Actions in Oracle Cloud"? We don't know the configuration of his environment...

Comment: It seems to me that the entire discussion is wrongheaded. Clearly in a traditional database, your statements would create the tables, and they would still be there later, if you are able to select from the last table after you created them. So, your focus (and everybody else's) should be on what is special about the cloud service, and/or Oracle Database Actions. For example, you may be logging in with some kind of "guest account", which is allowed to create objects (such as tables) for the duration of a session, but not to save them from one session to another.

Comment: And if that is indeed the type of issue you are having, professionals with 30 years experience working with Oracle Database, but who never used the cloud service, may still have absolutely no clue about the question you asked. (I am not one of them - I am not a computing professional at all, of any kind.) Instead of tagging your question as `sql` and `oracle` you might get better luck tagging it with things referring to the cloud database and Oracle Database Actions, if there are such tags on SO.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE BASE1 AS SELECT * FROM RAW_TABLE;
CREATE TABLE BASE2 AS SELECT * FROM BASE1;
CREATE TABLE BASE3 AS SELECT * FROM BASE2;
SELECT * FROM BASE3
```

Above is a valid query sequence for Oracle database. It should have been created three new tables in database. Since it's not happening please do the work in few steps to find out what's wrong.

First please check whether `RAW_TABLE` is available in database or not. Then try to select data from RAW_TABLE

```
select * from RAW_TABLE;
```

If all those are successful then try to create single table with below query:

```
CREATE TABLE BASE1 AS SELECT * FROM RAW_TABLE;
```

Hope you would find the problem by then.

DB-Fiddle:

Creating RAW_TABLE and populating data
create table RAW_TABLE (id int, name varchar(50));
insert into RAW_TABLE values (1,'A');

Query to create three more tables ans selecting from the last table:

```
 CREATE TABLE BASE1 AS SELECT * FROM RAW_TABLE;
 CREATE TABLE BASE2 AS SELECT * FROM BASE1;
 CREATE TABLE BASE3 AS SELECT * FROM BASE2;

 SELECT * FROM BASE3
```

Output:

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=07fe331ab21bf5aefd44ab4911bbf4a1)*

Comment: @xyzjayne Is there any update on your problem?

Answer (score 1):

your query fails because you are executing the whole script as one batch and each line is depends on another one , the transactional DBMS's work with blocks of code as one transaction , and that block of code doesn't commit until sql engine can parse and validate the whole block, and since in your block, BASE1 and BASE2 tables doesn't exists just yet , It fails.

so you need to run each statement as a separate batch. either by executing them one by one or in Oracle you can use / as batch separator, like in sql server you can use GO. these commands are not SQL or Oracle commands and are not sent to the database server , they are just break block of code in batches on your client ( like SQL*Plus or shell or SSMS (for Microsoft sql server), so It would look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE BASE1 AS SELECT * FROM RAW_TABLE;
/
CREATE TABLE BASE2 AS SELECT * FROM BASE1;
/
CREATE TABLE BASE3 AS SELECT * FROM BASE2;
/
SELECT * FROM BASE3
```

if your client doesn't support that then you only have to run them one by one in separate batches.

Comment: The question doesn't seem to be saying the code fails; but that the tables don't exist later. Also, DDL commits (twice; before and after the actual work); and if you have a semicolon and slash then it will try to create each table twice. (At least in SQL\*Plus etc; don't see why the cloud version would behave differently.)